# Detect aligned point in a scatter plot

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm looking to write a script that does automatic detection of vertically or horizontally aligned points as shown in the image below.

thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? What code did you write? What doesn't work?

Comment: I am looking for a lead ... If you have an idea, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.